# Trouble importing supporting QML files into Main.QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to make a QtQuick app with color themes. I plan to make a few .qml style sheets that define concepts like buttonColor, fontColor and so on. Here's an example of what the style sheets will look like more or less:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick

QtObject {
    property color bodyTextColor: "white"
    property color headerTextColor: "black"
    property int buttonBorderWidth: 3
    property color buttonColor: "#007bff"
    property color backgroundColor: "#000000"
    property color accentColor: "#6c757d"
    property int fontSize: 16
    property int titleFontSize: fontSize + 8
    property int labelFontSize: fontSize - 16
}
```

I tried `import "ClassicStylesheet.qml" as Styles` and it can't find it even though it's in the same root directory with Main.qml (I get a "no such directory" error). Using an absolute path to ClassicStylesheet.qml gets around this and the app runs, but it still doesn't *work*. I get the following error:

Could not find any constructor for value type QQuickColorValueType to call with value QVariant(QObject*, 0x0)
qrc:/[projectname]/Main.qml:31:17: Unable to assign undefined to QColor

All components render in black when running with an absolute path to the style sheet. Here's an example of my Main.qml file using my reusable LargeButton component (which renders fine using defaults, without the stylesheet) to create a main menu button:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

import "ClassicStylesheet.qml" as Styles

Window {
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test")

    Rectangle {
        id: menuFrame
        width: 600
        height: 400
        color: "lightgrey"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        radius: 25

        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            spacing: 10

            LargeButton {
                text: "Settings"
                buttonColor: Styles.buttonColor
                accentColor: Styles.accentColor
                fontColor: Styles.fontColor

                onClicked:
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice on navigating this? Why doesn't it recognize my file or read its contents? Thanks.

Comment: If it's in the same directory as Main.qml, you don't need any import statement at all. You can just access it directly, like this: `buttonColor: ClassicStyleSheet.buttonColor`. In QML, you import directories or modules, not individual files.

Comment: @JarMan thanks for the help, I didn't know that. But what I'm really trying to accomplish is aliasing the style sheets so I can swap between color palettes/themes in the app settings, so using them by name is not possible. Singletons don't support direct aliasing so I'm in search for another solution. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Even if imports worked the way you expected, I'm not really sure how aliasing would help you be able to change themes at runtime because you still need to define the alias explicitly. A different possibility could be [QQmlFileSelector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlfileselector.html). You would have multiple files named Styles.qml, each in separate folders, and you select which one to load based on the selectors that you specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to import a singleton file. You might need to supply a `qmldir` file.

```
singleton AppThemes 1.0 AppThemes.qml
```

In the following demo, there are two themes. A "light" and "dark" theme. These are available via the `AppThemes` singleton. The standard `Palette` format is used so that it can be assigned at a top-level component and it will be inherited by all controls underneath. Additional parameters, such as `fontSize` may be added.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    title: "AppThemes Demo"
    palette: AppThemes.current.palette
    ColumnLayout {
        RowLayout {
            AppButton { text: "File" }
            AppButton { text: "Edit" }
            AppButton { text: "Settings" }
            AppButton { text: "Help" }
        }
        AppLabel { text: "Pick a Theme" }
        Repeater {
            model: AppThemes.themes
            AppButton {
                text: modelData
                checked: modelData === AppThemes.currentName
                onClicked: AppThemes.currentName = modelData
            }
        }
    }
}

// qmldir
singleton AppThemes 1.0 AppThemes.qml

// AppThemes.qml
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick
AppThemesPrivate {
}

// AppThemesPrivate.qml
import QtQuick
QtObject {
    id: appThemes
    readonly property list<string> themes: ["light","dark"]
    property string currentName: "light"
    readonly property AppStyle current: appThemes[currentName] || light
    property AppStyle light: AppStyle {
    }
    property AppStyle dark: AppStyle {
        fontSize: 14
        palette: Palette {
            alternateBase: "#000"
            base: "#000"
            button: "#111"
            buttonText: "#fff"
            dark: "#666"
            highlight: "#d73"
            highlightedText: "#000"
            light: "#000"
            mid: "#444"
            midlight: "#333"
            placeholderText: "#80000000"
            shadow: "#888"
            text: "#fff"
            window: "#222"
            windowText: "#fff"
        }
    }
}

// AppStyle.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
QtObject {
    property int fontSize: 10
    property Palette palette: Palette {
        alternateBase: "#fff"
        base: "#fff"
        button: "#eee"
        buttonText: "#000"
        dark: "#999"
        highlight: "#38c"
        highlightedText: "#fff"
        light: "#fff"
        mid: "#bbb"
        midlight: "#ccc"
        placeholderText: "#80000000"
        shadow: "#777"
        text: "#000"
        window: "#fff"
        windowText: "#000"
    }
}

// AppButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Button {
    font.pointSize: AppThemes.current.fontSize
}

// AppLabel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Label {
    font.pointSize: AppThemes.current.fontSize
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. Part of what I'm trying to accomplish is aliasing the style sheets so I can easily swap between color palettes/themes inside the app, but as far as I'm aware singletons as objects don't support aliasing as per [link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36944).

Sorry to move the goalposts a bit. Is there another way to make this work? Any time I try to research a way to accomplish this task I just get links to the deprecated QtQuick.Controls.Styles and that's really clouding my research. Thanks again for clearing up the thing with importing files.